# Conversion. ps-->. pdf: text in gray!

Tags: conversion

When I generate the. Pdf from Ps  with GSview, printing quality is good. However, reading the screen. Pdf texts are gray ..... and makes reading difficult. Nevertheless, everything is ok for figures.

Have you an idea please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do u use PS at all? If you do not have a special reason then I would recommend using **pdftex/pdflatex**. This way you get directly a pdf file without conversion.

I made a **video tutorial** for a LaTeX workshop that shows the installation process and shows how to configure **Texmaker** in order to produce directly a pdf file. Maybe this helps:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RL15I-6NQFQ

As far as I know some  people are still using DVI and PS because they want to include **EPS** files or because they want to use the very powerful **PSTricks** package.

But EPS pictures can often easily converted into the PDF format or you produce the pictures as a PDF right away. And I think that you can use PSTricks with **pdftex/pdflatex** nowadays.

Comment: pdflatex produces files which are usually much bigger in size than those obtained via latex+dvips+gs or (even better) latex+dvipdfmx.  Furthermore the widely used pstricks package requires (I think) latex+dvips+gs. [oups sorry, this was in your message!]

Comment: @jfbu: Hello - I wasn't aware of that (bigger file size). Anayway - it's ***lockstep's*** turn to give us more information about his situation :).

Comment: I meant **researcher's** turn...